# Android iPhone Blackberry call forwarding

Tags: android, iphone, blackberry, phone-call, forwarding

I'm making a feasibility research for a mobile app (**iPhone**, **Android** & **Blackberry**) project. In short, there is a list of phone numbers, and if incoming call (caller id) is in that list, forward it to a specific(fixed) number (basic call forwarding). Has anyone made anything similar? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know anything about Android or Blackberry, but I know that this is impossible on an unjailbroken iPhone. If you want this, file a feature request!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have any information on how it can be done on **jailbroken iPhones**? I'm asking that because the client is not interested in commercializing the application - it's for internal use and he's not against using jailbroken iPhones.

Comment: You should probably split this into three questions, as you may get a different person providing a correct answer for each platform

Answer (score 1):

While BlackBerry provides an interface to monitor calls (inbound/outbound/historical) and provides a fair bit of data about them, no interface is exposed in BB that allows you to forward a call.  I believe that this is because forwarding is performed before the call actually reaches the BB device; so it's not the device that's doing the forward, but the carrier/pbx.

I think the answer will be similar for the other platforms, but I don't have experience with them.